# PhoneGap Error when Building App

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

BUilding my android app on PhoneGap. I left development for awhile and got a new phone and wanted to install my apk.

I havent made any changes to my code so it should just be able to build and be fine, but it is throwing this error:

```
Error - The following plugin, plugin version or a dependancy of this plugin is not on npm: org.apache.cordova.media-capture
```

My config.xml looks like this:

```
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="takenOutForSecurity" version="5.4.9">

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-6.3.0" />
    <preference name="android-build-tool" value="gradle" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />

    <name>Beer Portfolio</name>
    <description>Know Your Beer</description>
    <author href="takenOutForSecurity" email="takenOutForSecurity">Mike</author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="permissions" value="none" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />

    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />

    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
        <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" source="npm" />


    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" source="npm" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="port-xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="blackberry" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <access origin="*" />

    <gap:plugin name=" phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner" source="npm" />


    <gap:plugin name="uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator" source="npm" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-directions" source="npm" />


    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
        <string>We are using the Camera to scan barcodes</string>
    </gap:config-file>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" overwrite="true">
        <string>We are using the photo library to scan barcodes</string>
    </gap:config-file>




    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  - lower 4s -->
    <icon src="icon-57.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="152.png" gap:platform="ios" width="152" height="152" />
    <icon src="icon-120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="76.png" gap:platform="ios" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="icon-40.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />

    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch - 5-5s -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPhone6-6+ -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180" />

    <!-- Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="icon-29.png" gap:platform="ios" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="58" height="58" />

    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="80" height="80" />

    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" source="npm" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-geolocation" source="npm" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification" />

    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" source="npm" />

    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
</widget>
```

I did also try changing the `cli-6.3.0` to `cli-8.0.0` but that did not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 1):

In 2016, PhoneGap Build switched over to using NPM as a plugin host. More details [here](https://www.netkow.com/its-not-you-its-me-start-using-npm-for-phonegap-build-plugins-now/).

The standard Cordova plugins, such as media capture, now begin with "cordova-plugin" in their names. Try using [cordova-plugin-media-capture](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-media-capture) instead. In your config.xml, this would be:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-media-capture" spec="3.0.1" source="npm" />
```